# ¿por que en este codigo no funcionan las variables y demas problemas?

Tags: javascript, html, css

necesito hacer que funcione esta calculadora pero no sé que esta fallando:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
var operandoa;
var operandob;
var operacion;

function init() {
 //variable
 var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
 var reset = document.getElementById('reset');
 var suma = document.getElementById('suma');
 var resta = document.getElementById('resta');
 var multiplicacion = document.getElementById('multiplicacion');
 var division = document.getElementById('division');
 var igual = document.getElementById('igual');
 var uno = document.getElementById('uno');
 var dos = document.getElementById('dos');
 var tres = document.getElementById('tres');
 var cuatro = document.getElementById('cuatro');
 var cinco = document.getElementById('cinco');
 var seis = document.getElementById('seis');
 var siete = document.getElementById('siete');
 var ocho = document.getElementById('ocho');
 var nueve = document.getElementById('nueve');
 var cero = document.getElementById('cero');

 //eventos
 uno.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "1";
 };
 dos.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "2";
 };
 tres.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "3";
 };
 cuatro.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "4";
 };
 cinco.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "5";
 };
 seis.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "6";
 };
 siete.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "7";
 };
 ocho.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "8";
 };
 nueve.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "9";
 };
 cero.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "0";
 };
 reset.onclick = function (e) {
  resetear();
 };
 suma.onclick = function (e) {
  operandoa = resultado.textContent;
  operacion = "+";
  limpiar();
 };
 resta.onclick = function (e) {
  operandoa = resultado.textContent;
  operacion = "-";
  limpiar();
 };
 multiplicacion.onclick = function (e) {
  operandoa = resultado.textContent;
  operacion = "*";
  limpiar();
 };
 division.onclick = function (e) {
  operandoa = resultado.textContent;
  operacion = "/";
  limpiar();
 };
 igual.onclick = function (e) {
  operandob = resultado.textContent;
  resolver();
 };
}

function limpiar() {
 resultado.textContent = "";
}

function resetear() {
 resultado.textContent = "";
 operandoa = 0;
 operandob = 0;
 operacion = "";
}
function resolver() {
 var res = 0;
 switch (operacion) {
  case "+":
   res = parceFloat(operandoa) + parceFloat(operandob) break;
  case "-":
   res = parceFloat(operandoa) - parceFloat(operandob) break;
  case "*":
   res = parceFloat(operandoa) * parceFloat(operandob) break;
  case "/":
   res = parceFloat(operandoa) / parceFloat(operandob) break;
 }
 resetear();
 resultado.textContent = res;
}
```

```css
.calculadora{
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: #DC4C46;
 width: 300px;
 height: 500px;
 border-radius: 25px;
}

.calculadora td button{
 display: block;
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 font-size: 25px;
}

#resultado{
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 40px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 width: 300px;
 height: 100px;
 line-height: 100px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius: 25px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Calculadora con Javascript</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">

 </head>

 <body onload="init();">

  <table class="calculadora">
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><span id="resultado"></span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><button id="siete">7</button></td>
    <td><button id="ocho">8</button></td>
    <td><button id="nueve">9</button></td>
    <td><button id="división">/</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><button id="cuatro">4</button></td>
    <td><button id="cinco">5</button></td>
    <td><button id="seis">6</button></td>
    <td><button id="multiplicación">*</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><button id="uno">1</button></td>
    <td><button id="dos">2</button></td>
    <td><button id="tres">3</button></td>
    <td><button id="resta">-</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><button id="igual">=</button></td>
    <td><button id="reset">C</button></td>
    <td><button id="cero">0</button></td>
    <td><button id="suma">+</button></td>
   </tr>
  </table>

  <script src="Funcionalidad.js"></script>
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo tienes bien planteado, pero tienes algunos errores básicos de sintaxis.

El primero es que tienes los `id` de multiplicación y división acentuados con la tilde en el html, con lo que al intentar guardar luego en javascript una variable con el elemento del `DOM`, no reconoce ninguna `id`.

Otro error que tienes es en el `parseFloat()`, lo tienes escrito con c, `parceFloat()` está mal escrito.

Y el último, es que te faltan unos puntos y comas dentro del `switch` antes de los `break;`

```js
var operandoa;
var operandob;
var operacion;

function init() {
 //variable
 var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
 var reset = document.getElementById('reset');
 var suma = document.getElementById('suma');
 var resta = document.getElementById('resta');
 var prod = document.getElementById('multiplicacion');
 var division = document.getElementById('division');
 var igual = document.getElementById('igual');
 var uno = document.getElementById('uno');
 var dos = document.getElementById('dos');
 var tres = document.getElementById('tres');
 var cuatro = document.getElementById('cuatro');
 var cinco = document.getElementById('cinco');
 var seis = document.getElementById('seis');
 var siete = document.getElementById('siete');
 var ocho = document.getElementById('ocho');
 var nueve = document.getElementById('nueve');
 var cero = document.getElementById('cero');

 //eventos
 uno.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "1";
 };
 dos.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "2";
 };
 tres.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "3";
 };
 cuatro.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "4";
 };
 cinco.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "5";
 };
 seis.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "6";
 };
 siete.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "7";
 };
 ocho.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "8";
 };
 nueve.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "9";
 };
 cero.onclick = function (e) {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "0";
 };
 reset.onclick = function (e) {
  resetear();
 };
 suma.onclick = function (e) {
  operandoa = resultado.textContent;
  operacion = "+";
  limpiar();
 };
 resta.onclick = function (e) {
  operandoa = resultado.textContent;
  operacion = "-";
  limpiar();
 };
 multiplicacion.onclick = function (e) {
  operandoa = resultado.textContent;
  operacion = "*";
  limpiar();
 };
 division.onclick = function (e) {
  operandoa = resultado.textContent;
  operacion = "/";
  limpiar();
 };
 igual.onclick = function (e) {
  operandob = resultado.textContent;
  resolver();
 };
}

function limpiar() {
 resultado.textContent = "";
}

function resetear() {
 resultado.textContent = "";
 operandoa = 0;
 operandob = 0;
 operacion = "";
}
function resolver() {
 var res = 0;
 switch (operacion) {
  case "+":
   res = parseFloat(operandoa) + parseFloat(operandob); break;
  case "-":
   res = parseFloat(operandoa) - parseFloat(operandob); break;
  case "*":
   res = parseFloat(operandoa) * parseFloat(operandob); break;
  case "/":
   res = parseFloat(operandoa) / parseFloat(operandob); break;
 }
 resetear();
 resultado.textContent = res;
}
```

```css
.calculadora{
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: #DC4C46;
 width: 400px;
 height: 500px;
 border-radius: 25px;
}

.calculadora td button{
 display: block;
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 font-size: 25px;
}

#resultado{
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 40px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 width: 300px;
 height: 100px;
 line-height: 100px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius: 25px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Calculadora con Javascript</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">

 </head>

 <body onload="init();">

  <table class="calculadora">
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><span id="resultado"></span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><button id="siete">7</button></td>
    <td><button id="ocho">8</button></td>
    <td><button id="nueve">9</button></td>
    <td><button id="division">/</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><button id="cuatro">4</button></td>
    <td><button id="cinco">5</button></td>
    <td><button id="seis">6</button></td>
    <td><button id="multiplicacion">*</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><button id="uno">1</button></td>
    <td><button id="dos">2</button></td>
    <td><button id="tres">3</button></td>
    <td><button id="resta">-</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><button id="igual">=</button></td>
    <td><button id="reset">C</button></td>
    <td><button id="cero">0</button></td>
    <td><button id="suma">+</button></td>
   </tr>
  </table>

 </body>

</html>
```